# Click on a letter an show elements whose title has that letter with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something where I have an

```
<a href="#" class="alpha" data-letter="A">A</a> B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

search type thing. When "A" is clicked, I need to find my products on a page whose product title starts with the letter A. How do I do this? I figure the first step would be hiding all products, then somehow compare the title. Here's what my code looks like for the products:

```
<article class="product-grid-item product-block" data-product-title="Apple Computer" data-product-id="111" data-category_id="">

  <div class="product-item-details">
      <div class="product-item-brand">Apple</div>

    <h1 class="product-item-title">
      <a href="/macbook-pro" alt="Apple Macbook Pro">Apple Macbook Pro</a>
    </h1>

  </div>
</article>
```

times however many products I have.

```
//Step 1
$('article').hide();

//Step 2
compare click to title?
```

Comment: It's called "predictive search" Try this plugin from jQuery. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Not trying to do predictive search. It has to have the alphabet.

Comment: As for the markup, i edited the above. figure it would look something like that.

Comment: So select the elements, look over, read text, see if it is a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really, not a big deal, you practically wrote down what you have to do, for example hide all nodes and select those that match the pattern, or eventually iterate over all of them. Simple draft example: https://jsfiddle.net/prowseed/30vms2eb/

```
var arts = Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('.articles .article') );

document.querySelector('.letters').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.innerText.length == 1){
    for (a in arts) {
        if((arts[a].querySelector('.title').innerText)[0].toLowerCase() == e.target.innerText.toLowerCase()){
        arts[a].classList.remove('hidden');
      } else {
          arts[a].classList.add('hidden');
      }
    }
  }
}, null);
```

There is a lot of rubbish in this code, like for example check on click should look for some attribute rather than text length, but you have a basic idea.